# Move a 3d region into a specific bounding box

Tags: computational-geometry

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding `FindGeometricTransform`, but I thought `FindGeometricTransform[{p1,p2},{q1,q1}]` would give me a transform that maps `p1` to `q1` and `p2` to `q2`. Is this not the case?

In my example I have a 3d region `k` that I want to resize and transform into a bounding region of `Cuboid[{-0.05, -0.05, -0.5}, {.05, .05, .05}]`

[image]

Which doesn't work...

Comment: My guess is [`RegionResize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionResize.html) would be easiest here.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know how to properly post code.

Comment: @Feyre what's wrong with inline code?

Comment: @M.R. I don't think Feyre refers to the inline code, but to the screenshot of the code. The picture i) cannot be copied from, ii) is not permanent, iii) takes more memory than necessary --- iii) implies ii). Additionally, screenshots of inputs are quite ugly and user-dependent.